# Kentico 10 | Toolbar for Rich Text Editor in a Custom Component

Tags: properties, ckeditor, wysiwyg, web-parts, kentico

I can create a custom toolbar for the EditableText Web Part in Kentico 10, as there is plenty of documentation on how to create/set custom toolbars .. but I can ONLY find documentation for the EditableTextWebPart.

I need to create unique toolbars to be used within several custom Web parts for certain properties / fields. I can't find any documentation on setting them within my own custom Web part, and am hoping someone could point me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was under my nose, albeit a bit hidden.

1. In the /CMS/CMSAdminControls/CKeditor/config.js I added my own custom toolbar, which I had already created, but hand't figured out how to hand it off to the Web part property.

```
    config.toolbar_Caption =
    [
        ['Undo', 'Redo', '-'],
        ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'Scayt', '-'],
        ['Bold', '-'],
        ['InsertLink', 'Unlink', '-'],
        ['Maximize']
    ];
```

2. The web part has a property, named **Caption**, with the **Data type** set to *Long text* and the **Form Comtrol** set to *Rich Text Editor*.
3. Under **Editing control settings**, expand **Advanced** to access **Toolbar set** and set it to the custom toolbar. In my example, that would be **Caption**.
4. Also set the **Toolbar location** to **In** so that the toolbar is within the text area vs. floating on top of the entire form.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're mixing a few things up. Each webpart has properties. Each property has an associated control. The control you use is based on the datatype of the field.

If you have a long text datatype on your webparts property you should be able to pick the rich text editor as your control. Then create a custom widget for the WYSIWYG editor.

Now if you don't want to work with the WYSIWYG editor then, create your own [custom form control.](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/developing-form-controls)

[Check out this article](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/helpful-ckeditor-configurations-in-kentico) on customizing the WYSIWYG editor. At the end of the article it has a reference to custom widgets for your WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: My Custom Web Part does indeed have a Property (named caption) with a long text datatype and a rich text editor as its control. By your comment, it looks like maybe I need to create my own custom widget. I have not yet created a custom widget, so this is new territory for me.

Comment: Thanks Brenden, I had found those references, but they didn't really solve my specific issue. They did help guide me down a path for an entirely different feature I will need to build out, by demonstrating how to add widgets to web parts!